# Ubuntu, jack, maximum priority for audio application

Tags: bitwig

**OS, apps and hardware info**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-23-lowlatency #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 29 16:17:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jackdmp version 1.9.12 tmpdir /dev/shm protocol 8
Bitwig-studio version 3.0.1
USB2 Audio interface Tascam US16x02
```

**Question**

Is possible run audio application with max priority for this application? For best performance and lowest latency without cruckling/buffer problem for audio application.

**Situation**

I reinstalled `Ubuntu studio 19.04`, `update`, `upgrade`, install DAW `Bitwig studio 3.0.1`, then install `indicator-cpufreq` (for changing my cpu to best performance).

Then I ran `jackd` in this configuration.

```
/usr/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:US16x08 -r44000 -p128 -n2
```

I select in `indicator-cpufreq` applet `Performance` (for best performance), then checked via `lscpu` it is working.

```
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
CPU MHz:             3455.159
CPU max MHz:         3500,0000
CPU min MHz:         400,0000
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
```

Then I ran Bitwig studio. I tried do load some my older project.

**Issue**

When play the music in DAW, there are some crackling during the playing, and when I do something in DAW during playing (for example zooming or moving only), crackling is even worst.

Jackd log shows me many `xruns`.

I swear I had same configuration before reinstall OS and it was OK for this configuration, no crackling at all during playing even when working in DAW during playing or recording.

I tried install older versions of `Ubuntu studio`, no effect, crackling still present, same.

Why is now crackling due playing in DAW? Applet `indicator-cpufreq` changed to best performance, but seems not for DAW, no effect for `CPU load` in DAW when I selecting between `Performance` and `Powersave` in `indicator-cpufreq`, but `lscpu` shows me different `CPU MHz`.

What is the magic? Before I reinstalled OS, everything works fine. I found something about `nice` utility. Is it what I need to setup?

Thank you very much for any informations.

Comment: You don't need lowest latency for mixing, only for recording. I have no clue how to adjust that in nix, but the higher your audio buffer, the higher the latency, the more room the thing has to breathe = less break-up.

Comment: @PiedPiper Yes, I asked there already. :) But no anwer. I study `nice` about linux, maybe this is the way. I will write here if I found something important. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved**

Solved, this is what I did to get best performance after fresh ubuntu install. Priority set is important.

Install low latency kernel.

```
sudo apt install linux-lowlatency
```

Add new lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf

* - rtprio 70
* - memlock unlimited
* hard memlock unlimited
* soft memlock unlimited
```

Install some service to set cpu for best performance.

```
sudo apt install cpufrequtils
sudo cpufreq-set -r -g performance
```

or

```
sudo apt install indicator-cpufreq
(after reboot you will see applet in notification area for changing performance of cpu)
```

Reboot.

Install jackd2 if you don't have installed already.

```
sudo apt install jackd2
```

Get name of your hardware. For example, my hw: is `PCH`. Name of hw is in `[]`.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1228000 irq 130
```

Run jackd2 with parameters you need.

```
/usr/bin/jackd -d alsa -d hw:PCH -r 48000 -p 192 -n 3
```

You can change periods `-p`, frames `-n` and sample rate `-r` parameter for lowest latency. If crackling is present, this is your limit. `(Frames / Sample Rate ) * Periods = Latency in ms`.

Run DAW.

That's all. I hope this info could be helpful.

Bye.